# Simple mod rewrite redirect not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Hi I'm trying to code a mod rewrite that redirects /example to /example.php . The code looks like it should be working but it's not :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ /$1.php
```

error log file :

```
  [Mon Nov 21 04:13:27 2011] [error] [client 109.149.215.195] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
  [Mon Nov 21 04:13:31 2011] [error] [client 109.149.215.195] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
  [Mon Nov 21 08:26:23 2011] [error] [client 109.149.215.195] Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/chroot/home/content/86/8128686/html/college (None could be negotiated).

  [Wed Nov 23 16:33:55 2011] [alert] [client 109.149.215.195] /var/chroot/home/content/86/8128686/html/.htaccess: RewriteLog not allowed here

  [Wed Nov 23 16:43:23 2011] [error] [client 109.149.215.195] File does not exist: /var/chroot/home/content/86/8128686/html/missing.html
  [Wed Nov 23 16:43:39 2011] [error] [client 109.149.215.195] Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/chroot/home/content/86/8128686/html/index (None could be negotiated).
  [Wed Nov 23 16:43:39 2011] [error] [client 109.149.215.195] File does not exist: /var/chroot/home/content/86/8128686/html/missing.html
  [Thu Nov 24 02:46:47 2011] [error] [client 69.58.178.58] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/chroot/home/content/86/8128686/html/uploads/
  [Thu Nov 24 02:46:47 2011] [error] [client 69.58.178.58] File does not exist: /var/chroot/home/content/86/8128686/html/missing.html
```

thanks in advance

Comment: why is it not working? Whats your error? What happens? What doesnt happen? What does the log say? Is mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: @JanDragsbaek i don't know why it's not working hence the question , i get a 404 not found , where in the log do i look? , yes mod rewrite is enabled .

Comment: @JanDragsbaek : LOL: always same questions, always people who don't want to search by themselves... did you have a bad day? ;)

Comment: @OlivierPons Yes, a little :D

Comment: @OlivierPons I have searched but I'm pretty new to mod rewrite and the code looks like it should work .... I presume you know what's wrong with it ?

Comment: @FrankAstin I've posted something that should bring you on the right track (because today's not a bad day for me mwahahaaahhahah !)

Comment: @JanDragsbaek : your profile => your website => wow Php info, nice! All hand-compiled, you're one of the few real warriors around here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here's my advice:

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

Then the solution:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: Using the solution alone didn't work (brought up the 404 as before) . Adding the rewritelog directive caused the entire site to give a 500 error (i did update the log path) .

Comment: It's not possible that just adding the rewritelog directive could cause a 500. There's a problem with your whole configuration, not only with rewrite rules.

Comment: did you create a real vhost, i.e. directives between **`<VirtualHost *>`** and **`</VirtualHost>`**? In this vhost, did you create a real local server using `DocumentRoot`, `ServerName` and `ServerAlias`? Did you change your `/etc/hosts` accorgind to your `ServerName` so that you can type the server name and it points to your PC?

Comment: Hi , I'm using godaddy web hosting at the moment (I know) so none of the above . I've had a look on the godaddy support and they say mon_rewrite is enabled and should work as expected .

Comment: Hmmm , this is weird . It loads up the linked css file of the php document .

Comment: so please tell me what's in the `RewriteLog` file. Update your question with that (the `RewriteLog` file will be long I guess)

Comment: I'm going to get in contact with godaddy as this seems more like a shared hosting problem . I'll leave the question open and post the solution when/if I get it .

Comment: OK , got a pretty unhelpful response from go daddy . What I did find out is that they don't support the ReWrite Log . I did manage to access the error log file which I've added to the question above .

Comment: also the version of Apache they're running is 1.3.33 (2.2.13 on 4GH)

Comment: May I ask you to change your question so that the log is shown as a code (= one error per line)? And what it (are?) the URLs you tried? Are your sure there's only this rewriterules (the log shows that there may be more than this)

Comment: Sorry Oliver , This is all I could get from the error log that godaddy provides . As I mentioned they don't support the rewrite log (I hoped maybe you could see something i can't) . It's properly indented now .

Comment: Ok and what is (are) the URLs you typed in the browser to get those logs?

Comment: The url that brought up the css instead of the php was /fileupload , I also tryed /index which brought up nothing even though there is an index.php .

Comment: try to add the "/" in the `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /$1.php [QSA,L]` so try this: `RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)$ /$1.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: I'm going to give up on this one , just tried the same code in WAMP and it works fine . I sent Go Daddy another few E-mails but I've not heard anything back (they're advice was so vague I'm going to cancel my account next month) . Thanks for all your effort Oliver  , I may pester you in the future as my rewrite's get more complex :)

Comment: No problem Frank, check my reputation: I've done it almost on rewrite rules =)